# What is the problem in this pygame project I'm working on?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import os

WIDTH , HEIGHT = 1050,600

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("ok")

WHITE = (255,255,255)

FPS = 60 
CHARACTER_SIZE = (100,100)
CHARACTER_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Models','character.png'))
CHARACTER = pygame.transform.scale('character.png',CHARACTER_SIZE)
def draw_window():
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    WIN.blit(CHARACTER,(0,300))

    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        draw_window()
    pygame.quit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After running this I get this error:
argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str

reffering to this line of code:
CHARACTER = pygame.transform.scale('character.png',CHARACTER_SIZE)

What s the issue?

Comment: You need to load the image first! `pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("character.png",CHARACTER_SIZE)` or alternatively use the image you've already loaded!

Answer (score 0):

You can't transform a string. The first argument has to be the `CHARACTER_IMAGE` variable.